# Отображения прокрутки у списка

Tags: html, css

Есть список с изображениями

```
<div id="profile_photo_conteiner">
            <ul>
                <li>
        <img src=""/>
      </li>
                        <li>
        <img src=""/>
      </li>
                        <li>
        <img src=""/>
      </li>
                        <li>
        <img src=""/>
      </li>
                        <li>
        <img src=""/>
      </li>
                        <li>
        <img src=""/>
      </li>
                        <li>
        <img src=""/>
      </li>                 <li>
        <img src=""/>
      </li>
                        <li>
        <img src=""/>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Работает, но не появляется ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНАЯ (ось x) полоса прокрутки, проблему нашел в списках ul, если сделать не списком, а через блочные элементы div, то она появится (работает). Вопрос: почему она не работает? Код для тестов здесь [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97ngsa7g/2/). `float:left` указан, `overflow` для x и y тоже прописан, кстати контента тоже хвтатает, в примере указал около 10 элементов списка с изображениями, большую часть которого вы неувидите так как стоит `overflow-y hidden`, а в право элементы не сдвигаются следовательно нет и прокрутки. Почему?

css:

```
#profile_photo_conteiner {
height: 210px;
padding-top: 10px;
overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
max-width: 200x;
    white-space:nowrap;
    margin-bottom: 55px;
        border: solid 1px red;

}

/*-galery*//*
#profile_photo_conteiner ul {
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;

}*/


#profile_photo_conteiner ul li{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
    cursor: pointer;


}

#profile_photo_conteiner ul li img {
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Свойство `white-space:nowrap;` контейнера не действует в случае `float: left;` , для решения задачи нужно использовать `display: inline-block;`.

```
#profile_photo_conteiner ul li{
  // ... 
  display: inline-block;
  // ... 
}
```

Либо просто рассчитайте и задайте `width` для `ul`.